# How enable Typescript typing and intellisense for vue props in template in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I'm working with Vue and VS Code with vetur extension installed.

I've defined a `MyClass` class with two public attributes. Inside the "script" section i'm able to get proper intelisense for the `value` property.

But I cannot check intellisense nor typing enforcement inside the template. as the image below.

[image]

I should see only `enabled` and `number`.

How can I configure my VS Code to get this type enforcement on the template?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) extension:

In settings:

```js
"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true,
```

[image]

Comment: Get an error in the functional component with this option:
{{ props.author.fullName }}
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<{ author: IAuthorCard; } & Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>'. Did you mean '$props'?Vetur(2551)